# How to insert a date in sqlite from a monthCalendar control - c# - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, date

I want to copy a selected date from a monthCalender control to a sqlite db in c#.
Tried to do it with ToString : Gave me this form of string (MM-DD-YYYY-00:00:00 AM) and a logic error
from sqlite.
Tried doing it with ToShortDateString: It gave me this string (MM-DD-YYYY).
No error from sqlite until checking the record again.This time the error was "string was not recognized
as a valid DateTime".
I know the date format for sqlite is YYYY-MM-DD.
Do I have to convert the string?

```
    string startdate = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.ToShortDateString();
    string query = $"UPDATE status SET user = {listBox1.SelectedValue}" +
                       $" , userbadge = {listBox2.SelectedValue} "+ 
                       $" , date = {startdate}" +
                       $" WHERE status.id = {index}"; 
           
    openConnection();
    SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    closeConnection();
```

Comment: What's the table definition? And which driver are you using? I wouldn't recommend this for performing an update. It opens your application up for SQL Injection.

Comment: I really suggest using [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/parameters) (if this is Microsoft.Data.SQLite) . They make handling DateTime easier, too. In fact, that may make your problem go away completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can mitigate your problem simply by using [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/parameters):

```
command.CommandText =
@"
    UPDATE status SET user = $user, userbadge = $userbadge, date = $startdate WHERE status.id = $index
";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$user", listBox1.SelectedValue);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$userbadge", listBox2.SelectedValue);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$startdate ", startdate );
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$index", index);
```

According to [this docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/types), the value will be saved as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF".

Answer (score 0):

The solution with the parameters resulted in the same error.
After searching a bit further I found out that maybe converting the string would
do the job. And yes it worked!!!

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);
```

Comment: Ah, I somehow assumed `startDate` _is already_ a `DateTime`.